# asp.net QODBC Insertar datos en Quickbooks

Tags: sql, asp.net, odbc

Estoy realizando una aplicacion web la cual es un formulario para insertar informacion en la base de datos de quickbooks.
El problema esta en que cuando le doy a enviar me dice que todo esta bien, pero, en quickbooks no esta la nueva informacion insertada

Este es el codigo html del formulario:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"        CodeBehind="Formulario.aspx.cs" Inherits="quickbooks_01.Formulario" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Formulario</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
 <body>

<div class="container pt-3">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2>Formulario de registro</h2>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre</asp:Label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Apellido</asp:Label>
             <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtApellido" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre de la compañia</asp:Label>
             <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Telefono</asp:Label>
             <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTelefono" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</asp:Label>
             <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </div>
        </div>

        <asp:Button ID="btn_enviar" runat="server" Text="Enviar" OnClick="btn_enviar_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Aqui esta el codigo para que inserte la data del formulario:

Este es la conexion

```
   public  OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Quickbooks Data; OLE DB Services=-2");
```

Esto es lo que sucede cuando le das clic al boton Enviar:

```
 protected void btn_enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            string query = "insert into customer (name, firstname, lastname, companyName, Phone, Email) values ('" + txtCompany.Text + "', '" + txtNombre.Text + "' ,'" + txtApellido.Text + "','" + txtCompany.Text + "','" + txtTelefono.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "')'";
            string query2 = string.Format("insert into customer (name, firstname, lastname, companyName, Phone, Email) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')", txtCompany.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text, txtCompany.Text, txtTelefono.Text, txtEmail);
            cn.Open();
            OdbcDataAdapter db = new OdbcDataAdapter(query2, cn);

            cn.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            txtNombre.Text = "";
            txtApellido.Text = "";
            txtCompany.Text = "";
            txtTelefono.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
        }
 }
```

Creo que el problema esta en este pedazo de codigo, lo hice o intente hacer de dos formas distintas:

```
   string query = "insert into customer (name, firstname, lastname, companyName, Phone, Email) values ('" + txtCompany.Text + "', '" + txtNombre.Text + "' ,'" + txtApellido.Text + "','" + txtCompany.Text + "','" + txtTelefono.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "')'";
  string query2 = string.Format("insert into customer (name, firstname, lastname, companyName, Phone, Email) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')", txtCompany.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text, txtCompany.Text, txtTelefono.Text, txtEmail);
```

Me hara falta algun dato en el  para que la informacion sea enviada correctamente, etc.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser por que te confundiste y pusiste: `txtEmail` en vez de `txtEmail.Text`

```
string query2 = string.Format("insert into customer (name, firstname, 
lastname, companyName, Phone, Email) values 
('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')", txtCompany.Text, txtNombre.Text, 
txtApellido.Text, txtCompany.Text, txtTelefono.Text, txtEmail.Text);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Manuel Dominguez por tu ayuda, un amigo me ayudo en el problema y se dio cuenta que esta linea de codigo, aunque estaba bien escrita no cumplia con lo que yo queria : OdbcDataAdapter db = new OdbcDataAdapter(query2, cn); , deberia de sert OdbcCommand db = new OdbcCommand, muchas gracias nuevamente